# Connecting To Remote MySQL Server - Connection Refused

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, remote-access

So, I have a problem in trying to talk to a remote MySQL server, which is on a Digital Ocean host (Ubuntu). My other host is on IPOWER, but their SQL capabilities are not so great so I wanted my PHP files on IPOWER to talk to my MySQL database on Digital Ocean.

I keep getting an error, "connection refused" however.

This is what it looks like from the IPOWER side:

`mysqli_connect('$myDigitalOceanIP', '$myUserName', '$myPassword', 'database', '3306');`

On the Digital Ocean side I have done the following:

- Lifted the firewall and IPTables restrictions on port 3306
- Created a new user in the MySQL that comports with $myUserName with
  Select, Insert, and Update permissions that can connect from any IP.
- Flushed privileges in MySQL console and restarted the MySQL and
  Apache services
- Confirmed that MySQL is listening on port 3306.
- Edited the my.cnf file so that `bind-address` is commented out so
  that connections outside of the localhost can be accepted.

With all of this, I am still getting connection refused. Please throw additional suggestions my way!

Also, is there an error log I should be looking at? The Apache access and error logs yield me nothing and I couldn't find a SQL error log. Do I have to enable it somehow?

Comment: "Connection refused" is a lower level TCP error that will not directly be caused or logged by mysqld.  `netstat -a -n | grep 3306` to sanity check that you are indeed listening on 0.0.0.0:3306.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Putting that command in yields me the following, which I believe confirms I am listening on 3306: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: You are indeed correct. It's listening as it should be. If the firewall on the server also looks good, verify that neither provider has any kind of firewalling on the connection -- inbound at the MySQL side, outbound at the PHP side -- that would be the next thing I would suspect, something intermediate is blocking you.  See if you can just `$ telnet digitaloceanip 3306` (from elsewhere, for testing).  MySQL Server doesn't actually speak telnet, but you can connect with it for testing and see the semi-human-readable handshake packet, including the server version.

Comment: The step after that would be checking out `tshark`.  Running it on the MySQL machine should help you confirm that packets aren't actually arriving.  `sudo tshark 'tcp port 3306'`.  You should *not* see the connection attempt if the packets are being blocked externally, but you would see them if your firewall is misconfigured.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `tshark` doesn't work for some reason, but digitalocean support says they can `telnet` at the 3306 port.

Comment: It might be worth briefly going wide open on the firewall and iptables to be sure you don't have something inadvertently blocking the traffic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That seems dangerous :P

Comment: Not the greatest idea ever, but if you're stuck, you have to try *something*.  And you're stuck.  The circumstances you describe don't justify the behavior you observe.  You can always figure out what you did wrong, then wipe the vm and get a new one, if it makes you that uncomfortable.  Not everybody might admit it, but we've all done it at one time or another.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did as you advised and re-did my droplet with no firewalls/IPTables restrictions. Turns out it was IPOWER's problem, not mine, see the new answer. Thank you for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I *was* doing everything right, the problem was on the IPOWER side. I had a friend remotely connect to the SQL server on Digital Ocean and he did so in five seconds.

The lesson here is don't let the customer choose the host, and don't use a crappy host like IPOWER that suggests you downgrade PHP and interferes with your remote connections for no reason.

Following the steps outlined in the question should resolve this for anyone in the future, so long as they use hosts that allow them to configure options themselves and don't intentionally try to mess with them.